# Matlab - equivalent of R's rep() with times argument

Tags: matlab, vector, rep

I am wondering what is the fastest way to achieve in Matlab what in R I would achieve with the `rep()` function with the `times` argument, e.g.

```
v1=1:5;v2=5:1;out=rep(v1,times=v2);out
# 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 5
```

i.e. replicate each element in vector `v1` a number of times given by the corresponding element in vector `v2`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `repmat` or `repelems`, e.g.

```
 z = repelems(x,[1:4;rep])
```